# Unable to copy OSX Installer from external drive to Mac

Tags: macos, finder, hard-drive, usb

As usual I wanted to prepare bootable USB with OSX. Some time ago I've made a copy of my Mavericks, Yosemite and El Capitan to external drive.

I wanted simply to drag & drop El Capitan to [prepare USB drive](http://slick.pl/kb/os-x/creating-bootable-usb-flash-drive-os-x-mavericks/).

After dragging El Capitan app file to desktop I get

[image]

The point is, that my `Desktop` does not contain this file. What's wrong? The same happens to all 3 files. I cannot copy them. Are those files corrupted? In a meanwhile I'm downloading new file form App store...

This disk was plugged into Windows multiple times. Is it possible that Windows damaged **app** files? I've noticed that Windows treats `app` files as folders so maybe it changed the content?

Comment: From your screen capture, it seems that you already have a file (or folder) named "Install OS X El Capitan.app" on your Desktop. The error message seems to be a correct one.

Comment: This window is from my external USB drive. Not the Desktop.

Comment: And just below the Finder window of your USB content is the icon of the existing file (or folder) named "Install OS X El Capitan.app" which is on your Desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in the Finder app of OSX. Options you can try :

- Instead of drag-dropping you can try right click -> Copy Item and
  then paste it on the desktop
- Try copying the files through terminal command.
- Try making a folder on the desktop, and then copy the files in the newly created folder.

Reference : [Apple Discussions](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2231287?start=30&tstart=0).

Answer (score 1):

I tried Terminal even as the first option but **no luck** in my `iTerm`. Then I tried all combinations with dragging and dropping and right click copy and paste. Nothing worked.

Finally I went level up and dragged and dropped parent folders called `OSX`. First time it just created empty `OSX` directory in my `Desktop` with the same error message. But when I did it for the second time, it started copying all 3 big installers.

It's absolutely weird. So finally it's done. I'm writing this response from clean, formatted El Capitan.

Up for Shaggy for all efforts!

Comment: I'm glad i could help. As i mentioned in the answer, it is a bug in the Finder and it's behavior is totally random. Please consider accepting it if it helped you.

Comment: @ShaggyD, you said that this is a well known problem on El Capitan. I see that now it happens with all files I copy form external USB. Can you paste some link to this problem?

Comment: The problem is not on El Capitan, it's in the Finder app. The link I've given in my answer is the only relevant link that addresses this problem.